# does assigning a `package` to `publisher` changes `dart pub publish` behavior?

Tags: flutter, dart, package, publish

[pub.dev](https://pub.dev/) `Package ownership` states:

> You can transfer this package to a verified publisher if you are a
> member of the publisher. Transferring the package removes the current
> uploaders, so that only the members of the publisher can upload new
> versions.
>
> Upgrading to verified publishers is an irreversible operation.
> Packages can be transferred between publishers, but they can't be
> converted back to legacy uploader ownership.

seems quite clear that, has a member of the publisher,

I can upload that package, but before going ahead I wonder:

***is there any change in `dart pub publish` authentication and behavior in general?***

Comment: If I understood the question correctly, after transferring you can still add others or yourself (if transferring to other, you have to ask them to add you) as members to update the package. It wont affect the authentication, I myself authenticating with same behavior as previously with individual owner.

Comment: @SahdeepSingh that's exactly what I meant, thanks m8
if you make it an answer I'll accept it straight away

Comment: made it the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After transferring you can still add others or yourself (if transferring to other, you have to ask them to add you) as members to update the package.

It wont affect the authentication, I myself authenticating with same behavior as previously with individual owner.